# ec2 driver Test Kitchen config error

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

I cannot figure out why I keep getting this error with a custom AMI in test kitchen:

```
"Failed to complete #create action: [undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass] on image5.0_new"
```

Here is the plaforms stanza in the .kitchen.yml:

```
platforms:
 - name: image5.0_new
   driver:
     image_id: ami-8c5236ea
   transport:
    username: root
    ssh_key: /opscode.pem
```

I have the driver line correct but I don't know why it's not seeing the correct username... any ideas?

Comment: Pleas run with `-l debug` and include the stack trace

Comment: output http://pastebin.com/Tsrp85Ch

Comment: In the future it is easier to just edit it into the question

Comment: kitchen-ec2 has some issues with the yaml parsing. Check out the configuration used on this issue and see if it works for you:
https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-ec2/issues/244